# Examples of a complement of a convex set being convex

Tags: geometry, convex-analysis

I am having trouble thinking of any examples of a complement of a convex set being convex. It just doesn't make any sense to me as to how the complement can be convex instead of concave. The only one I can even think of would be the complement of the empty set, but is the empty set even convex?

Comment: Think of a half-space...

Comment: If I were to take the complement of a convex set in a half space, would the complement be the other half space on the other side?

Comment: The empty set is also convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A convex set is one in wich for every two points in the set, the line connecting them also lies $\textbf{entirely}$ within the set.

For an exemple of a convex set whose complement is also convex just consider the upper half-plane, i.e take $\mathbb{R}^2$ with standard coordinates $x,y$ and consider the set
$$U=\{(x,y)\in\mathbb{R}^2 : y>0\}$$
it is clearly convex and so is its complement.

Comment: So could that be generalized into saying the complement of any half plane is convex?

Comment: @Andre: The complement of a half plane / space is also a half plane / space.

Comment: For a convex set $A$ to have a convex complement $A^C = S \setminus A$, it's clearly sufficient for $A$ to be a half space of $S$, as the answer states.  But I'm curious - is it also a necessary condition?  That is, if a convex set $A$ has a convex complement, then must it also be a half space.  I'm having some trouble coming up with a proof sketch, but I intuitively believe it's true.